# Soundcloud modify the waveform color

Tags: jquery, canvas, html5-canvas, soundcloud

I am creating a website based on soundcloud and i need to modify the soundcloud waveform color to look like the following

[image: How it should be]

I read in the blog of soundcloud and it seemed like waveform.js will do the trick but still i am getting something like this

[image: How it looks now]

Can anyone let me know how can i get the exact same effect. I saw on soundcloud homepage they are doing same thing using canvas but i don't how exactly to do that. The image waveform returned from soundcloud api is as follows

http://w1.sndcdn.com/1m91TxE6jSOz_m.png

Can anyone guide me the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of composite mode and clipping to achieve this without iterating through pixels (which means CORS won't be a problem in this example):

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/g4t667nj/)**

[image: Waveform progress]

**The essential code:**

Assuming image has been loaded, canvas setup we are good to go:

```
function loop() {

    x++;        // sync this with actual progress

    // since we will change composite mode and clip:
    ctx.save();

    // clear background with black
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    // remove waveform, change composite mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);

    // fill new alpha, same mode, different region.
    // as this will remove anything else we need to clip it
    ctx.fillStyle = '#00a'; /// gradient
    ctx.rect(0, 0, x, h);
    ctx.clip();             /// set clipping rect
    ctx.fill();             /// use the same rect to fill

    // remove clip and use default composite mode
    ctx.restore();

    // loop until end
    if (x < w) requestAnimationFrame(start);
}
```

If you want the "unplayed" waveform to have a different color simply style the canvas element with a `background`.

Comment: Hi, i guess this will do the trick but there is only one problem. The progress bar will be a div like `<div class="sc-played" style="width: 15.889212957354365%;"></div>` and the width gradually increases with the progress of the song. Is there any  way i can do the progressbar like this ? If you need to see my site then i can send you the url.

Answer (score -2):

If you are integrating soundcloud with iframe, you can't modify it.

Don't forget the cross-domain policy, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: No, i am not using soundcloud in iframe.I am using soundcloud api.

Comment: What you want to do is same like first example of the Examples section ?
http://waveformjs.org/

Comment: No, in that case they have a white background with black image. The main thing is the progress bar. The progress doesn't look like it should, the rest is fine.